# Ubuntu Shared Folder Symbolic Link

Tags: symbolic-link

I am new to Ubuntu. I just installed Ubuntu using VMware. I added a shared folder and used

```
sudo vmware-config-tools.pl
```

to confirm the change. The shared folder exists in /mnt/hgfs under the name UbuntuShared

I want to create a symbolic link. But my problem is the shared folder is not located in C drive. It is in G Drive.

I tried

```
ln -s /mnt/hgfs/UbuntuShared G:/UbuntuShared
```

But it says no such file or directory. I saw a lot of posts having the source folder as /usr/... or ~/... . BUt my folder is in drive G: and I dont know how to link it.

Additionally, I installed my VMWare in G: Folder.

I could not find a similar post, and I apologize if this is a duplicate post. Any solutions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Folder G: drive C: etc. are Windows partition identifiers, which will not work in linux.
For creating the soft link, go to the directory where you want to have the link, and execute the command

```
ln -s /mnt/hgfs/UbuntuShared
```

Comment: A little clarification, go to the shared folder in Ubuntu terminal inside VM or go to the original folder in cmd outside the VM?

Comment: Could you clarify ? I am new to navigation in Ubuntu.